# Debugging service worker 'trying to install' in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

I have what I assumed was a pretty standard service worker at http://www.espruino.com/ide/serviceworker.js for the page http://www.espruino.com/ide

However recently, when I have "Update on reload" set in the Chrome dev console for Service Workers the website stays with its loading indicator on, and the status shows a new service worker is "Trying to Install".

Eventually I see a red 'x' by the new service worker and a '1' with a link, but that doesn't do anything or provide any tooltip. Clicking on `serviceworker.js` brings me to the source file with the first line highlighted in yellow, but there are no errors highlighted.

I've done the usual and checked that all files referenced by the service worker exist and they do, and I have no idea what to look at next.

Does anyone have any clues how to debug this further?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Chrome Beta.

I updated to the newest release a magically everything works. So I guess it was a bug in Chrome or the devtools, not my code.

Comment: Saved my day. Perfect answer.

Comment: This is happening on the latest stable chrome version (Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Comment: Can confirm I am also seeing this in Chrome 84.0.4147.135 and Chrome 85.0.4183.83

Comment: Same problem here with Chrome 84.0.4147.135 - just updated to 85.0.4183.83 (Win10) but did not help at all. Anybody got some more information about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For those running in to this issue with the latest version of Chrome, I was able to fix it by caching each resource in its own cache. Just call `caches.open` for every file you want to store. You can do this because `caches.match` will automatically find the file in your sea of caches.

As a messy example:

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
 event.waitUntil(swpromise);
 var swpromise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {

 for (var i = 0; i < resources_array.length; i++) {
   addToCache(i,resources_array[i]);
 }

 function addToCache(index,url) {
   caches.open(version+"-"+index).then(cache => cache.addAll([url])).then(function() {cacheDone()});
 }

 var havedone = 0;
 function cacheDone() {
  havedone++;
  if (havedone == resources_array.length) {
   resolve();
  }
 }
})
```

I used the version number and the index of the file as the cache key for each file. I then delete all of the old caches on activation of the service worker with something similar to the following code:

```
addEventListener('activate', e => {
 e.waitUntil(caches.keys().then(keys => {
  return Promise.all(keys.map(key => {
    if (key.indexOf(version+"-") == -1) return caches.delete(key);
  }));
 }));
});
```

Hopefully this works for you, it did in my case.