# Since Chrome 85 cache.addAll of Service Worker does not cache with Cache-Control to "no-store"

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, browser-cache, cache-control

If you are using `cache.addAll` or `cache.add` in your Service Worker, pay attention to your `Cache-Control` configuration in your `.htaccess` or elsewhere.

With the new version of **Chrome 85**, using the `no-store` value for `Cache-Control` prevents Service Worker from cache files.

Furthermore, the Service Worker fails to install and your website/application could be compromised.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: This is likely due to a [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1124632) that has since been resolved.**

That's not the expected behavior. I don't see any mentioned of "no-store" in the [Service Worker Specification](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/), and I don't see anything in [ChromeStatus](https://chromestatus.com/features) indicating that that change was made.

I also can't reproduce the issue on Chrome 85.0.4183.83 for the Mac.

Running the following code in the JS console, for instance, leads to a successful cache addition:

```
cache = await caches.open('test-cache');
await cache.addAll([
  'https://httpbin.org/response-headers?Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate&X-Test=1',
  'https://httpbin.org/response-headers?Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate&X-Test=2',
  'https://httpbin.org/response-headers?Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate&X-Test=3',
  'https://httpbin.org/response-headers?Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate&X-Test=4',
  'https://httpbin.org/response-headers?Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate&X-Test=5',
]);
```

What makes you think it's not working, and can you point to a reproduction of the issue?

Comment: Thanks Jeff pour your response. 
Try to use for example this line in your .htaccess :
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"

Comment: Also using single file cache is not showing the issue.
Try to use an array of at least 5 elements and use cache.addAll(array) of this array.

Comment: I just updated the example to add 5 entries at once with that `Cache-Control` response header, and still can't reproduce a failure.

Comment: This is likely due to installing service workers being throttled.  This was a feature I enabled last week, but causes problems with cache.addAll().  I've disabled it as of today.  It should take affect the next time you restart your browser.  See https://crbug.com/1124632.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your comment. It looks like the same concern as the bug you mentioned. Although, restarting the browser does not fix anything

Comment: There is another issue in StackOverflow related :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63675460/chrome-85-service-worker-stuck-on-trying-to-install

Comment: FYI, after fixing the problem with cache.addAll(), I've re-enabled throttling network requests in install events.  Based on trials and measurements I don't think this will cause problems like this question again, but I wanted to mention it here.  See: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/KlgQ-j0Wx0U/m/_qD70G5zAwAJ